# Ubuntu 16.04 Software Center Just Spins

Tags: software-center

I just installed ubuntu 16.04.1 and the software center just displays the loading spinner when I try to select packages.  I tried installating dropbox by manually downloading the `.deb` file and opening it, but that causes the software center to open, and it just displays the spinner again indefinitely.

Comment: An alternative: `sudo apt install gnome-software`. If that gets stuck loading too then the problem is not likely due to a problem with the software center.

Comment: Before anything else makes sure your system is fully updated: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: Hmmm - That's weird - gnome software was what was coming up.  I removed it and installed the ubuntu software center and now it works.